# Error while running app in android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

So I have just started my first app in which I have a button and when user clicks on it then it just print the message.

But when I build the app and when I run that app on android studio's console then after opening it crashes and then it stops working.

Meanwhile I have searched for the error and they suggested me to see logcat table or the text file in which I can easily see the errors but after it I am stuck because I have no idea that how can I solve such problem.

Please help me with it.

Comment: You should post your logcat with the errors. Also your code so we know what the issue is.  Post your activity and layout.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how capable you are with android and you haven't given us much info to work with.
could you post a brief description of the logcat from launching the apk to the apk actually crashing?
the logcat is gonna be the best option to diagnose it.
Are you using the android sdk and emulator?
Have you updated the resources and api's?
If you go into the resource list there should a online repo with a whole lot more SDK bits you might find help.
What api's and android version is your apk built from and is your emulator emulating the same android build?
Could be the apks GUI resolution or script related, have you checked through it all?
Microsoft visual studios has a very good debug system  and trouble shoot but I'm not sure if android is compatible as I've only used wp8 on it. Worth finding out though.